# Macbook stuck at login screen

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, login

My macbook is stuck on the login screen after entering the password. I've been using this MBP for the past 4 years and it's been slowing down of late. However, I'm now having trouble logging in to my primary account: after I enter the password, I can proceed no further, although I still have access to the Guest account.

I've gone through some of the steps mentioned here and in other forums: resetting PRAM, reinstalling MacOS, etc. I ran disk utility and I'm getting an error. What should I do?

Comment: Hey, welcome to Apple.SE! please add all relevant details, including OS version, and what error did you get in Disk Utility, and what "etc" did you do? This will prevent answers based upon guesses..

Answer (score 1):

You need to backup the disk ASAP before your data is lost.  Then replace the bad hard drive and I would reinstall macOS from scratch on the new drive.  Last copy your data back to the drive.  If you have a time machine backup you can restore that to the new hard drive in one step.

Give us some model info on your Mac and we can advise you more.